# How to tune period for MOSFET IRF3205 with gate driver optocoupler PC817?

Tags: arduino, mosfet, frequency, opto-isolator, switching

I want to test 100W power output using coils for wireless power transfer project. I used 2 IRF3205 MOSFETs with 2 gate driver optocouplers PC817. I used Arduino for optocouplers. The problem is I don't know how to tune the turn-on and turn-off time for the MOSFETs. The frequency is 80kHz and duty cycle is 50% so the period is 12.5 us and each turn-on and turn-off time is 6.25 us. But when I test the resistor 10 ohm in the receiver side, there is no current output. Can someone help me for this problem?

[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: Pc817 are not gate driver optos. Show your schematic.

Comment: I use gate pulse voltage instead of optocoupler in schematic. I want to give 12 V and signals for switching period  to gate of MOSFETs by using optocouplers.

Comment: sorry, that simulator diagram doesn't mean much.

Comment: how to calculate the switching period of mosfet 1 and 2 with delay time of optocouplers for my circuit?

Answer (score 1):

If the top fet is turned on, then the source is at 20V but the gate is only at 12V - clearly this won't work. Turn off time will be slow as you are discharging the gate charge through a 2k resistor.

Use a half bridge mosfet driver like a IR2110 or easier still, use an integrated half bridge like a L298 (there are better choices, but this is what sprang to mind). No optocouplers needed.

I'd also suggest you use the pwm feature of the AVR timers